# Did any SciFi or fantasy movie/tv use "Hit the road, Jack" and which one was first?

Tags: history-of, music

"Hit the road, Jack" is a very popular song and [used in plenty of films and TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit_the_Road_Jack#References_in_popular_culture).

But that list doesn't include any SciFi or fantasy movies or TV. That's not conclusive - I know the Wikipedia list is incomplete because it didn't include my favorite use, from "Failure to Launch". Despite its name it's a romcom, not an astronaut movie so it doesn't count.

Was it ever used in a SciFi or fantasy movie or TV at all? If so, which one was the first one to use it?

Answer (score 3):

It's listed on the soundtracks of [Escape from New Jersey](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1753790/?ref_=_4) and [Ella Enchanted](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0327679/?ref_=_7). I'm not sure if [Space Cowboys](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0186566/?ref_=_9) count as SciFi.

Comment: Space Cowboys is absolutely scifi.